# What does "only to have" mean in the sentence below?

Tags: meaning

What does **only to have** mean in this sentence:

> Iberville seized Fort Nelson in 1694, only to have the English recapture it in 1696.

Comment: Have you [checked a dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/only-to-do-sth)?

Answer (score 1):

What an interesting question!  According to [the Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/only+to):

> only to (do something):
>
> **An expression used to highlight an upsetting, disappointing, or
> otherwise unpleasant action that occurred immediately after something
> else.**
>
> I worked on that proposal for over a month, only to find that they had
> awarded the contract to the firm across town.
>
> It can be disheartening to spend a lot of time preparing a meal only
> to have your kids turn their nose up at it.

The fort was taken but then lost, which was a disappointment.